# PHP preg_split and keeping only the entire regex as a delimiter, ignoring inside parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to use a more complex regex and preg_split on a string to get an array of all matches and keep the delimiter. Normally this would be simple, but trying to use PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE and having multiple sets of parentheses in my regex is proving to be difficult. I'll elaborate:

I want to parse an IP address in a line and break the whole line into an array so I can do something with only the IP specifically, but I want to display the entire line eventually (I'm applying formatting to the IP and then re-assembling and displaying the string). My regex for that is this (it checks for something that looks like an IP, but it doesn't check validity, I don't care at this point):

```
(((\d{1,3})\.){3}(\d{1,3}))
```

Now, my code for the time being is this:
    $ipv4regex = "/(((\d{1,3}).){3}(\d{1,3}))/";

```
if (contains_ipv4($line)){
    $pieces = preg_split($ipv4regex, $line, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($pieces);
    print "</pre>";
}

function contains_ipv4($val){
    return (preg_match($ipv4regex, $val));
}
```

And here is a sample of my output (IP address changed, but still relevant):

```
Array
(
    [0] => show arp results from 
    [1] => 10.10.15.120
    [2] => 15.
    [3] => 15
    [4] => 120
    [5] => 
)
```

How can I change it so that the output is as follows:

```
(
    [0] => show arp results from 
    [1] => 10.10.15.120
    [2] => 
)
```

Essentially I want to capture only the outer-most parentheses in my regex for PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE, and not the inner ones. I know that I can change my regex for this particular case, but I've got a "proper" IPv6 regex with a LOT of parentheses and I'm afraid that it will be near impossible to rewrite with only one set of parentheses on the outside. Could anyone help me out? I'd greatly appreciate it. Or, if there's an entirely different means to my end that I'm missing, feel free to point me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can desactivate parentheses capturing by adding `?:` just after the open parentheses, for example :

```
((?:(?:\d{1,3})\.){3}(?:\d{1,3}))
```

Comment: You are welcome :) (don't forget to mark the question as answered)

Comment: Unfortunately I solved it a different way, but I cannot answer my question for another hour or so. This way would work, but it's not how I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reduce the overall clutter of the method and improved it to use only a few lines of code:

```
if (preg_match($ipv4regex, $line)){
    $line = preg_replace_callback($ipv4regex, 'add_ipv4_p', $line);
}
```

I then print the line later on, but this simple bit is all I need for regex checking 
The method add_ipv4_p is the method I use to apply formatting to the first element of the array passed to it. Simple. I was able to add more formatting options to the code by just re-using this snippet and changing the regex and formatting method.